# Not all headers are shown with Firebase onRequest

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to learn Firebase while making a small project, where I need to store IP addresses in my system.

But I realized that it's not working like I'm used to work with Express. 
I need the exact same result of this Gist: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6fffffb45ee5cbfbca6c3511e5d19528#gistcomment-2674393

However doing the same things doesn't work for me, I don't get so many headers and also not getting the client IP address.

```js
exports.getPolls = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(util.format(req.headers))
});
```

> Header's I get

```
headers:
   { host: 'localhost:5001',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
     'user-agent':
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3370.152 Safari/537.36',
     accept:
      'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'en,nl;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8',
     cookie: 'io=AVNO7ouAHOYCkVK8ADSD',
     'if-none-match': 'W/"5-qvTGHdzV6LKavt4PO0gs2a6pQ00"' 
    },
```

I need the client IP address

Comment: What is `console.log(req.headers)` and `console.log(req.headers['fastly-client-ip'])` printing out?

Comment: @Nathan `console.log(req.headers)` is just printing what I have mention above 'Header's I get'. `console.log(req.headers['fastly-client-ip'])` prints out `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/541

> Short explanation:

when doing `firebase serve` the request headers are coming from an emulator which has not the expected headers, `firebase deploy` is what you need to do.

Going to the `firebase console` > functions (choose your function) > logs, would show the expected headers (with the `x-forwarded-for` header) when you console log like me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`exports.myip = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     console.log(req.headers['x-forwarded-for']);
     return res.status(200).send(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].toString());
});`

Comment: My `req.headers` does not have so it will return `undefined`

Comment: @buryo please deploy the myip function and check if it returns undefined